# Tableau - table formatting, stop merging/centring

Tags: tableau-api

I can't figure out an option I'm sure Tableau has.

Its easier to explain with visually so I'll show you what my table looks like and what I'd like it to look like (at least when I export to excel).

Looks like:

```
Date  Group   
1st     a           
        b           
        c   
2nd     a           
        b           
        c
```

What I would like:

```
Date Group    
1st    a    
1st    b    
1st    c    
2nd    a     
2nd    b    
2nd    c
```

So I'd like no merged or blank values as at the moment when I export to Excel I have to unmerge and then manually fill the blanks which for large sets of data is a nightmare.

Comment: I know how to do it in excel (and using macros) but excel is so slow and its a lot of data.

Comment: Instead of exporting data, try to copy data and paste on an excel

Comment: I eventually figured this out. The problem is if you have multiple measuring values instead of two or more columns it has a measure column followed by a measure value column.

In this instant I was only looking at two measures so did it once for each, but in the future this may become annoying. 

Thanks

Comment: Then you make pivot table to get the data in the format you need

Comment: My broader advice would be to stop using Tableau as a intermediate tool, and use it to deliver the final product. The only reason to export Tableau data to excel is to make further calculations. Tableau is far superior than Excel on data visualization, and can perform most calculations Excel does. Eliminate the Excel from your process, you'll be happier

Comment: I figured out if you leave the measuring values in the marks bit and dont put it in the abc bit of the table then click view data it has all the columns normally. Easy.

And Im using excel for calculations. Tableau is just an easy way to pull the data I want rather than using SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

1. Put the row's distinct value (aka - deepest level of detail) in your first column.
2. Use the View Data feature under Analysis in the Menu bar (also found in other places).

Answer (score 2):

What you can also do is create a calculated field and then add all the Dimesions you are using.  Add this to the left side of the shelf and then right click and untick "Show header".  It will now export as you wanted, you will just have to delete Column A.

Comment: Ive figured out a way to do it, but i'd like to try your way.

When creating the calculated field I cant add more than one measure unless im going to do some sort of function including them both. 

Where on the left side should it be added (under marks I assume, thats how I figured the other way out) and where should I right click?
Thanks

Comment: That's what this answerer is saying... create a Calculated Field like: `[Date] + [Group]` and call it "Combined Dimensions" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create a calculated field then just input index() in it;add this field to the left side and hide it.